# Outbound Twilio call from the browser

Tags: websocket, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am building a dialer with twilio nodejs typescript and next js (full stack)

I am making a call to a receiver using the client.calls.create() method from my server
I want to be able to communicate with the receiver if only the call is answered by humans and not machine (voice mail) this will be done, by clicking a button (join-call) from the front end, twilio device from the front end will be connected to the receiver and communication made over the browser.

kindly point me to docs, links of how to implement this. Also if you have done something similar, kindly share.

I created a TwimL as shown below to handle the call and once a receiver picks up the call, the call ends after say "hello from here"
I was expecting the receiver to be on the line for as long as he chooses to end the call.

> `` !     const twiml =  !         `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> !         <Response> !         <say>Hello from here</say !         <Response>` !       ; ! ``

Comment: This is the expected behavior. From you question, it seems you actually planning to make a [Build In-Browser Call with Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-calls)